# Using Coalesce, How do I not display null values?

Tags: sql, database, coalesce

I am using the following query in my database:

```
Select ID, coalesce(FName,MName, LName, 'Missing Name') as 'NameToCall', [Phone Number] from Emp
```

The results show:
[image: Query results]

I want the ID 6 to not display when the query executes. How do I do it?

I've so far tried taking the column named

```
FName
```

outside of the colaesce but, it only displays the whole FName column

Comment: You can do `select id, phone from emp where fname is not null and mname is not null and lname is not null` to show all records except the 6th one.

Comment: `or`, not `and`...

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, phone from emp where coalesce(FName,MName, LName) is not null
```